# When do hook_views_data() and hook_views_data_alter() get called?

Tags: views

I'm working on a site I inherited that has a functioning `hook_views_data_alter()` implementation. I can see things in the Views editor that it has added. However, I cannot figure out how on earth to get that function to be called again so I can change the data. I am running xdebug with a breakpoint in the function body, and nothing I do, from editing a view, to adding a relationship, to clearing the cache or rebuilding the registry, trips that breakpoint. Not even putting `module_invoke_all('views_data_alter');` in index.php. What do I need to do to get Drupal to run that hook again?

Comment: Do you have caching enabled for this view (under advanced tab)? In which module/template does this hooks_views_data_alter function reside?

Comment: Those hooks implementations are normally put in a MYMODULE.views.inc file; `module_invoke_all('views_data_alter');` doesn't do anything because the file containing the hook needs to be first loaded.

Comment: @longboardnode: No, no caching on the view. Yes, the hooks are in my custom module's `.views.inc` file, and I know that file is being read (xdebug tells me that)... I just can't figure out what action I need to do for the functions to actually be executed. Weird!

Comment: @longboardnode, no dice with `_views_fetch_data_build()`. I also emptied those two tables; no luck there either. One really important question is, what front-end action would **ordinarily** cause those functions to execute? If all were working right, what URL would I have to hit to invoke them? Maybe I'm just not doing the right action.

Comment: @JohnAlexander actually I just deleted my comment because I think Kiamlaluno's comment is more accurate. How is your views.inc file loaded?

Comment: @kiamlaluno, my hooks are indeed in MYMODULE.views.inc, and I can confirm that the file is at least being loaded. When I put a breakpoint at the top of the file, it does get tripped. But it never executes those functions. What front-end action usually causes them to be executed? Hitting a certain URL? I'm totally lost...

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else is making the same mistake I was, here's the answer.

1. First of all, `hook_views_data()` will not ever, ever be called if you put it in yourmodule.module. It has to be in yourmodule.views.inc.
2. You should probably implement `hook_views_api()` to tell Drupal where your yourmodule.views.inc file resides; for example with code similar to the following one.

   ```php
   function yourmodule_views_api($module = NULL, $api = NULL) {
     return array(
       'api' => '3.0',
       'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'yourmodule') . '/includes/views',
     );
   }
   ```

This tells Drupal that yourmodule.views.inc can be found at yourmodule/includes/views/yourmodule.views.inc. If you don't implement `hook_views_api()`, put the .inc file in the same folder as your .module file.

Once you have this set up, `yourmodule_views_data()` will be called when you clear the caches.

Comment: The Draggableviews module contains an example of hook_views_data_alter being called within a .module file.  The breakpoint can be tripped when rebuilding the cache through the UI.  Clearing it through drush, as I was doing, executed the code but didn't trip the breakpoint (with my xdebug setup anyhow).